# Query the name of the top X people on transaction count from a different table

Tags: mysql

I'm messing around with the Sakila sample database in MySQL and I would like to get the top two people who rented the most movies.  I've tried a few things and my most recent attempt is:

```
SELECT c.last_name, Count(r.rental_id)as NumberOfRentals FROM customer c
INNER JOIN rental r ON c.customer_id = r.customer_id
ORDER BY NumberOfRentals DESC
LIMIT 2
```

It only returns the first name in the database though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause.  Without having one defined, MySQL will aggregate all the rows which match the given parameters into a single row, instead of aggregating them based on a defined criteria (the `last_name` in this case).

```
SELECT c.last_name, Count(r.rental_id)as NumberOfRentals FROM customer c
INNER JOIN rental r ON c.customer_id = r.customer_id
GROUP BY c.last_name
ORDER BY NumberOfRentals DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Doh. Knew it was something simple. Thanks!